# How can I know if some of the money in my bank account is blocked and not available for withdrawal?

Tags: india, ipo

I am a resident of India and have a savings account opened with HDFC bank. Recently I applied for an IPO for which INR 14K were blocked from my account. The IPO was not allotted to me and hence the money was supposed to get released. I didn't get any notification for the money getting released.

I am just wondering how can I know if the money is still blocked or not. I haven't found anything related to this on Bank's app.

Comment: This would be highly dependent upon the bank and their banking application.  Some will clearly indicate money on hold, others will not.

Comment: Chase Bank has something like "Account Balance" versus "Available Balance" or "Available for Withdrawal". I'll have to check.

Comment: Chase calls it "Available" (I have immediate access) versus "Present" (contains funds which have not cleared yet)

Comment: Thanks guys. I found it in the app. For anyone curious about the HDFC bank, under the account details section, you will see "Amount on hold" that will tell the amount blocked in account and the Account balance will tell the total amount including the "Amount on hold"

Comment: I had the same question when I had applied for an IPO through my HDFC Bank account after a few trials & errors I got the answer through their Mobile Banking App. Just like you said.

Comment: @KunalGupta Maybe you can write an answer based on your experience.